# Trigger to insert new row into second table causes "Connection is busy with results for another command"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, trigger, insert, sap

I have created this trigger to insert new row into table `@AL_ORDR_TRACKER` after new row is inserted in table `ORDR`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgAfterInsertORDR ON dbo.ORDR
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO dbo."@AL_ORDR_TRACKER"
        (U_DocEntry, U_Updated)
    SELECT
        DocEntry as U_DocEntry, GETDATE() U_Updated
        FROM inserted
END
```

The trigger gets registered but when inserting new rows into `ORDR` I get the error message:

`Connection is busy with results fro another commands`

What might be going wrong here?

Comment: Is `@AL_ORDR_TRACKER` a table? Why are you double quoting it?

Comment: @McNets, yes it is.

Comment: What client driver and programming environment?  It appears that the client connection is not busy with results from another command, which suggests you're reusing a single client connection object for multiple concurrent operations.

Comment: Is there any other trigger involved?

Comment: It looks like you have [MARS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-multiple-active-result-sets-mars?view=sql-server-2017) enabled and there is a result set active from another command. Can you post the connection string so we can check?

Comment: @kirchner It all involves SAP B1 which is pretty complex application. I have discovered that triggering the action on UPDATE is sufficient since UPDATE is also triggered when new rows are inserted in the original table.